# Troubleshoot simple summation function

Tags: python, sequences

I want to create f(n) for 
Sn = n(n+1)/2. Does this make sense? I feel like a nerd!

Here's what I wrote:

```
def f(x):
    sum=n(n+1)/2
    print(sum)
```

Comment: Please include your code as text, not image.

Comment: You need to use f(n) instead of f(x).

Answer (score 1):

A few issues with your code:

- Programming languages don't know the mathematical convention of omitting a multiplication symbol.
- You need to keep your variable names consistent.
- You should use integer division since `n` is an integer number and therefore also the sum.
- Don't use `sum` as a variable name, as it makes the built-in function `sum()` inaccessible.
- You probably don't want to print the result in the function but return it to the caller.

Instead of

```
def f(x):
    sum=n(n+1)/2
    print(sum)
```

you need to write

```
def f(n):
    return n*(n+1)//2
```

and then do something like `print(f(100))`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
def f(n): 
    sum=(n*(n+1))/2 
    return sum
```

Note that:
- **return** should replace **print** in functions. Nonetheless, **return** should be the last thing your function does. Anything after **return** will yield an error.

Now, you can call your function and send input to it as follows:

```
print(f(5))  #eg. 5
```